# TensorCircuit error mitigation

Tags: tensorcircuit

Does TensorCircuit provide built-in error mitigation methods? To see the effect of error mitigation I would like to insert noise channels in the circuit (this is given through tc.channels), then use unitary folding and  extrapolate to zero noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the question. TensorCircuit currently supports scalable readout error mitigation (https://github.com/tencent-quantum-lab/tensorcircuit/blob/master/examples/readout_mitigation.py
). Other methods are in development and will be released soon.